# Is charge conservation violated when inserting a dielectric in an isolated capacitor?

Tags: electrostatics, conservation-laws, charge, capacitance

This is part of a solved textbook problem
In an isolated plane capacitor, with square plates of length d , separated a distance h, a dielectric is inserted a distance x. As part of a longer energy problem we need to find the charge density distribution on the capacitor in function of x

[image]

Since the capacitor plates are equipotential an the charge is kept constant (isolated capacitor)
the electric field is the same in both the volume 1  without dielectric and the volume 2 where there is dielectric. $(\sigma_1)$  and $(\sigma_2)$  denote the charge density on the respective parts of the capacitor. $\kappa$  is the relative electric permittivity. 
[image]

the total charge is:
[image]

Solving the system for $(\sigma_1)$ and $(\sigma_2)$ yields:
[image]

What I can’t explain myself is that if in  the expression for the total charge q,  I consider the cases for

$ x=0 $,  $  q(0)=(\sigma_1)d^2$

$ x=d$ ,  $  q(d)=(\sigma_2)d^2$

where q(x) is the total charge in the positive plate when the position of the dielectric is x 
Since the  total charge is constant I was expecting  $q(0)=q(d)=q(x)$ for any x from 0 to d , but we know  $\sigma_1$  and $\sigma_2$   are different because they are related by the electric permittivity of the material as seen in the first equation above, so  $q(0)$   $\neq$  $q(d)$ and then charge conservation is violated.  What is going on here, why aren't the equations reflecting charge conservation?

The problem states to consider the total charge is kept constant,since it is isolated

Comment: The total charge on each plate is constant, because the capacitor is isolated, and the equations should reflect that

Comment: I am confused by your notation. When you write $q(0) = ...$, what does the argument to the $q(\cdot)$ function represent? Is it the position in the structure, or is it the distance the dielectric has been moved?

Comment: q(x) is the total charge in the positive plate when the position of the dielectric is x

Comment: Then you should just have $q(x) = Q$, where $Q$ is the charge that was initially on the plates when you started inserting the dielectric.

Comment: yes, that is my point, at that should be constant for any x, but I don't understand why the equations are not saying so.

Comment: No, they aren't constant for any $x$. As you push the dielectric further between the plates, the way the charges re-distribute will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have forgotten that $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are both functions of $x$.

So, following your notation :
$$q(0) = \sigma_1(0)d^2=\frac{q}{d^2} d^2=q$$
$$q(d)=\sigma_2(d)d^2=\frac{\kappa q}{d(d+(\kappa-1)d)}d^2=q$$

And likewise it holds for any $x$. This makes sense because we explicitly used the following equation to derive $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ :
$$q = \sigma_1(d-x)d+\sigma_2 xd$$

Answer (score 0):

> Since the total charge is constant I was expecting q(0)=q(d)

This can't be.

For the plates to remain at equipotential, some of the charge has to move from the part of the plate without inserted dielectric to the part of the plate with dielectric inserted in between.

The total charge remains constant as you move the dielectric body. But the charge re-distributes itself between the two regions of the plates in order to keep the conductive structures at equipotential.

Comment: I know it re-distributes itself but the total sum should be constant, q is the total charge on each plate

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver, yes, keeping the total charge constant should be one of the constraints on your solution.

Comment: Yes, they do re-distribute to account for the presence of the dielectric, and make the whole region equipotential. So charge density is not uniform in this problem